# Late 2015 iMac frequent kernel panics

Tags: imac, high-sierra, kernel-panic

I have performed memtests that result in no failures, as well as tested the health of the 1TB SSD in this machine. I have pulled the RAM and placed new RAM. I have reset NVRAM. I have completely wiped and installed Big Sur fresh. I am still getting intermittent and seemingly random kernel panics.

Even when reinstalling **again**, back to Sierra, I'm actually getting panics after a fresh install, before the setup is complete. It typically shows the following:

```
 Kernel Extensions in backtrace:

 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[85A525E4-C60E-345C-B651-6266952AFCA5]@0xffffff80134e0000->0xffffff80134f6fff
 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet(11.0)[73A1490B-9377-3E9A-9C2C-24849A44C8BB]@0xffffff801350e000->0xffffff8013531fff


    dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[D4B89780-21D2-3499-8CC1-E92275BA0604]@0xffffff8013766000->0xffffff801376afff
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[59A305C2-E322-3EA6-B8DB-475512053CDE]@0xffffff8013244000->0xffffff8013245fff
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[85A525E4-C60E-345C-B651-6266952AFCA5]@0xffffff80134e0000->0xffffff80134f6fff
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4E85D41F-6AD7-3C24-911C-A8B80B599F86]@0xffffff801376c000->0xffffff8013794fff
    dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily(985.2)[65E1B8DA-D7E4-3F0E-8108-440507F8C0F7]@0xffffff80139ba000->0xffffff80139d5fff
```

Comment: Why do you think it's network-related?

Comment: I do not think it's network related. I am only showing the relevant output of `Kernel Extensions in backtrace`. It is the same output every time.

Comment: Assuming you are using Ethernet, did you try to change the LAN cable?

Comment: I did use a different cable, yup. It may have just been a conicidence, but when I unplugged the cable from the machine, it kernel panicked again. Just as a test, I've decided to keep it unplugged and have no networking on it at all to see if it panics again. I've also noticed that every time this happens I've been using a Cat 6 cable, not like that would mean much, but I'm curious to try it with a Cat 5 cable next. I recognize how silly that sounds.

Comment: I had no crashes staying off the internet, then decided to reconnect using different cables as well as trying Ethernet to Thunderbolt adapters, which started the crashes again. What would cause that?

Comment: Bad cables, bad/broken port, …

Comment: I don't think this is your problem but I remember my dad's older iMac (late 2000s?) freezing up (but not a kernel panic as such) when connected to the internet. This issue didn't happen when it was not connected to the internet. The solution was to change IPV6 to IPV4 in `Network preferences`. Again, I don't think this will be the solution, but may as well try!

Comment: Oh well, still crashing randomly. Seems like once a day. There are absolutely no issues being found in any hardware diagnostics being run. I also captured the running temperatures of the CPU and GPU even right before the crash and nothing comes back hot. Should I open it up and at least clean it out? It's a completely clean OS install...nothing 3rd party and no detected failing hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved after updating to Monterey. I have absolutely no idea what ultimately the problem was, but I haven't had this issue since updating last week:

```
kriss-iMac:Downloads kris$ uptime
 8:32  up 6 days, 23:01, 3 users, load averages: 1.71 2.16 1.93
```